# Check if user has permission to access a url (for use with logon return url)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When a user logs on, I check if there is a return url, and if so I redirect to it, as per the MVC application template.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{          
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

How would I check if this URL was valid (routes to a controller/action), and the user has permission to access it?
My actions are all protected using the standard authorize attribute.

Thanks for your help,

Stew

Comment: While I accept you might have good reasons for wanting to do this I will ask one question, what are you going to do if the user doesn't have access to said, albeit valid, URL?

Comment: Redirect them to a standard landing page - this is to cover the case where a different user has logged off, and the return url is set to a page that the next user logging on doesn't have permission to access (different role). I don't want them to see my standard 'no permission' page, but instead I want them redirected to the standard landing page for that type of user

Comment: How can 2 user share the same ReturnURL? Do they use the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally protect a specific URL via the web.config file not inside your code. See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815151).

Comment: I'm not trying to protect urls (which is done by using the mvc authorize attribute), just present a different pretty page to  'you do not have permission to access this url', but only for when a user first logs on, in the (albeit unlikely) event they have a return url set to an area of the site they don't have permission to access.